how to access translated values in Odoo 17?
I have created a form in Odoo and it contains fields with the translation feature.
The user has already entered the translated values, and I need to access them in order to use them in a QWebReport. Is it possible to to create a QWebReport that includes a value and it's translation ??
I have tried to introduce a function that retrieves the translated values but when i try to use them in the QWebReport, it doesn't recognize them. this is the function I used:
def generate_report(self):
    # Retrieve records
    records = self.search([])

    # Prepare data for the report
    report_data = []
    for record in records:
        # Retrieve translated values of fields
        trans_nom = record.with_context(lang='ar').nom
        trans_prenom = record.with_context(lang='ar').prenom
        trans_lieu_realisation = record.with_context(lang='ar').lieu_realisation
        trans_decision_conseil = record.with_context(lang='ar').decision_conseil

        # Append data to report_data list
        report_data.append({
            'trans_nom': trans_nom,
            'trans_prenom': trans_prenom,
            'trans_lieu_realisation': trans_lieu_realisation,
            'trans_decision_conseil': trans_decision_conseil
        })

    # Render the Qwebreport with the data
    report = self.env.ref('acces.imprimer_fiche_etudiant_action').render({
        'docs': report_data,
    })

    return report

I also tried if-else statement to make sure that there isn't a problem somewhere else, but it only seems to not recognize the translated values, everything else works just fine.
I would really appreciate if anyone share their ideas and/or solutions about what could be done in such a case.

How do you use them in die report? What is your overall requirement? Do you really want to "show" translations to each other or just load/print a report in different languages?

I am required to create a custom certificate of attendance that should have each value in french and in Arabic all in the same page, for people with different background languages.
I wanted to add other fields instead of the translation feature to store each value in a variable for better control, but my superior didn't agree to that, they said it's better to keep it that way
and what is a die report?

Oops my German got through :D I meant "the report". You can also load other language values directly in the (die :-P) report. Just load the whole record with another language like in your example above: <t t-set="my_record_in_ar" t-value="o.with_context(lang='ar')" /> and use it everywhere you need the other translations, for example <span t-field="my_record_in_ar.trans_lieu_realisation" />.

I modified die ;D report as you said. I added this line:  and now it says that 't-field' cannot be used on a t element

It has to be a span or a p node, something where html is doing output.

same issue, it doesn't recognize any value that was translated

I am starting to wonder that maybe Odoo doesn't have that function at all, because it is possible to create a QWebReport using the translated values but only if you include one language. Two languages is not an option I guess.
Because it's been more that 3 days and I haven't found anything

Printing a report completely in another language is working like a charm. So i'm wondering, why you don't get any other values. You're sure the fields are translatable and also translated for the printed records?

yes, I made sure of that and I checked many times
the report must be printed completely in another language.
As example, the user can fill the form in french and then type the translated values for his name, surname, and city using the translation feature of odoo.
And the document,when printed, should contain his name, surname, and city in both Arabic and french in the same page

You need to use the locale code to set/get locales for user, in your case it's ar_001 not ar
You can find an example in l10n_gcc_invoice(arabic english invoice):
<t t-set="o_sec" t-value="o.with_context(lang='ar_001')"/>

